# While deploying the bicep template I am getting bad request error error

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am trying to deploy a function app `Linux consumption plan` using bicep but when I am using below code I am getting an bad request Error When I am deploying to azure portal using SDK.

```
param functionAppName string = 'func-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
 
@allowed([
  'Standard_LRS'
])
param storageAccountType string = 'Standard_LRS'

param location string = resourceGroup().location
 
param appInsightsLocation string = resourceGroup().location
 
@description('The language worker runtime to load in the function app.')
@allowed([
  'node'
])
param functionWorkerRuntime string = 'node'

param linuxFxVersion string

param packageUri string

var hostingPlanName = functionAppName
var applicationInsightsName = functionAppName
var storageAccountName = '${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}azfunctions'

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
}

resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

resource applicationInsight 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: applicationInsightsName
  location: appInsightsLocation
  tags: {
    'hidden-link:${resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', functionAppName)}': 'Resource'
  }
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
  kind: 'web'
}

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux'
  properties: {
    reserved: true
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
}
```

I have modified several times but still getting the same error.
Any suggestions form any one, Thanks in advance.`

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed the function app  `Linux consumption plan`  using below Bicep template.

Thanks to  [@mumian](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/function-app-arm-templates/blob/main/function-app-linux-consumption/main.bicep)  for Bicep template.

> properties: {
> reserved: true
> serverFarmId:  [hostingPlan.id](http://hostingplan.id/)

As show above add the`serverFarmid:hostingPalan.id`

> value: reference(resourceId(‘Microsoft.Insights/components’, functionAppName), ‘2022-03-01’).InstrumentationKey

Add  `2020-02-02`  in place of  `2022-03-01`  because the Api version is still not available in Azure portal as shown below.

[image]

```
@description('The name of the Azure Function app.')
param functionAppName string = 'func-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'

@description('Storage Account type')
@allowed([
  'Standard_LRS'
  'Standard_GRS'
  'Standard_RAGRS'
])
param storageAccountType string = 'Standard_LRS'

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Location for Application Insights')
param appInsightsLocation string = resourceGroup().location

@description('The language worker runtime to load in the function app.')
@allowed([
  'dotnet'
  'node'
  'python'
  'java'
])
param functionWorkerRuntime string = 'node'

@description('Required for Linux app to represent runtime stack in the format of \'runtime|runtimeVersion\'. For example: \'python|3.9\'')
param linuxFxVersion string

@description('The zip content url.')
param packageUri string

var hostingPlanName = functionAppName
var applicationInsightsName = functionAppName
var storageAccountName = '${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}azfunctions'

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
}

resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
    tier: 'Dynamic'
    size: 'Y1'
    family: 'Y'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

resource applicationInsight 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: applicationInsightsName
  location: appInsightsLocation
  tags: {
    'hidden-link:${resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', functionAppName)}': 'Resource'
  }
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
  kind: 'web'
}

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux'
  properties: {
    reserved: true
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', functionAppName), '2020-02-02').InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: toLower(functionAppName)
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: functionWorkerRuntime
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
          value: packageUri
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    applicationInsight
  ]
}
```

After successful deployment to azure, portal go to your resource group as shown below.

[image]